# lodash how to set value in multiple paths

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking at the `_set` and `_setWith` function in lodash but I need to be able to use a catch all argument.

```
object = {"root": {"a": null, "b": null, "c": null}}};
path = ["root", "*"];
_.set(object, path, 1);

console.log(object)
>>> {"root": {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1}}}
```

I only showed it with one `*` but I would also need it to work if the path had multiple for example `["root", "*", "*"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take function which checks if a placeholder is given and fork the recursion or update all keys.

```js
function setValue(object, [key, ...rest], value) {
    if (key === '*') {
        Object.keys(object).forEach(rest.length
            ? k => setValue(object[k], rest, value)
            : k => object[k] = value
        );
        return;
    }
    if (rest.length) {
        setValue(object[key], rest, value);
        return;
    }
    object[key] = value;
}

var object = { root: { a: null, b: null, c: null } },
    path = ["root", "*"];

setValue(object, path, 1);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: I think this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a practically recursive set with `_.set`.

You can use `_.mergeWith` and write your own customizer.

Link to [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith).